# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: linux, bash, centos, python3, sqlite

We have different python version installed and specifically using `python3.7` so I have edited my `.bashrc` file. We are using `Centos7` with `Linux` server.

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=
# User specific aliases and functions
alias python=python3.7
alias pip=pip3.7


[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ python
python             python2.7          python3.6          python3.7          python3.7m-config
python2            python3            python3.6m         python3.7m

[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ which sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3
```

Its working with `python2.7` and `python3.6` version

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3

[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ python3.6
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:34:55)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
```

It's not working with `python3.7` version

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ python3.7
Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep  3 2020, 09:25:25)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

**Update-**

We installed python following instruction in the below link
[Python3.7 installation link](https://www.osradar.com/install-python-3-7-on-centos-7-and-fedora-27-28/)

Hence my `python3.7` version is installed at root level

```
[root@innolx20122 ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg  Python-3.7.0  Python-3.7.0.tgz
[root@innolx20122 ~]# cd Python-3.7.0
[root@innolx20122 Python-3.7.0]# ls
aclocal.m4    config.status  Doc         Lib              Mac              Misc     PC              pyconfig.h     python-config     setup.py
build         config.sub     Grammar     libpython3.7m.a  Makefile         Modules  PCbuild         pyconfig.h.in  python-config.py  Tools
config.guess  configure      Include     LICENSE          Makefile.pre     Objects  Programs        python         python-gdb.py
config.log    configure.ac   install-sh  m4               Makefile.pre.in  Parser   pybuilddir.txt  Python         README.rst
```

I saw one link on stack overflow suggesting some workaround.
[fix Sqlite3 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126475/importerror-no-module-named-sqlite3-in-python3-3/25721685#comment113213608_25721685)

Kindly suggest if it's ok to run below commands from same root directory itself

```
yum install sqlite-devel

./configure
make && make altinstall
```

Comment: How were the modules in /usr/local installed?

Comment: @ jsbillings .. some one else installed python3.7 version. I will check but looks like he followed given link instructions https://www.osradar.com/install-python-3-7-on-centos-7-and-fedora-27-28/

Comment: [xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/eksinvi/.local/bin:/home/eksinvi/bin

Comment: I saw one answer but have not tried it.. don't know whether it is safe to do so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553065/default-python-usr-bin-python-instead-of-usr-local-bin-python

Comment: It is **NOT** safe to follow those instructions in the answer on that page.  Replacing `/usr/bin/python` on CentOS 7 will break a bunch of core components, including `yum`.  You need to either use a packaged python and stop using your broken python installation in /usr/local, or fix your broken python installation. It appears to have a bad sqlite module installation.

Comment: @ jsbillings.. Could you please suggest an answer or workaround. I am not sure how to proceed with this further. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use the python 3 that is part of the OS?  Otherwise get support from the person who installed your broken python in /usr/local/.

Comment: @jsbillings.. I was scared but I tried below commands and luckily it worked. :-) Thanks a lot for your support and guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I logged in as `root` user.

```
[root@innolx20122 ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg  Python-3.7.0  Python-3.7.0.tgz
```

and then navigate to the `Python-3.7.0` directory

```
[root@innolx20122 Python-3.7.0]# ls
aclocal.m4    config.status  Doc         Lib              Mac              Misc     PC              pyconfig.h     python-config     setup.py
build         config.sub     Grammar     libpython3.7m.a  Makefile         Modules  PCbuild         pyconfig.h.in  python-config.py  Tools
config.guess  configure      Include     LICENSE          Makefile.pre     Objects  Programs        python         python-gdb.py
config.log    configure.ac   install-sh  m4               Makefile.pre.in  Parser   pybuilddir.txt  Python         README.rst
```

thereafter ran below commands to resolve the issue.

```
yum install sqlite-devel

./configure
make && make altinstall


[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ python3.7
Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep 26 2020, 23:18:27)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>>
```

Comment: omg it worked for me (python3.8.3) thank you